# Handle Entity Framework On Create POCO

Tags: entity-framework, events, poco

I'd like to see if there's a way to hook into the Entity Framework context so I know as soon as it has finished creating a POCO object.

Are there any attributes I can use, such as with [OnDeserializing]? The purpose is to set a few values on the object as soon as the context is done creating it from a database fetch.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hook into the ObjectMaterialized event fired by ObjectContext.  In CTP5, you need to cast your DbContext like so in the constructor for your DbContext:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += 
    this.ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized;
```

If you are not using Code First, you don't need to cast.  Then implement your function `ObjectContext_OnObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)`.  Via the EventArgs, you will be able to access your object, which has just been materialized.