# Entity Framework - Eager loading Linq query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I need to eager load the ExceptionAppointment in the following scenario.

I have 3 tables: Appointment, ExceptionOccurrence, ExceptionAppointment with the following relationships

- Appointment has a 1:m relationship with ExceptionOccurrence
- ExceptionOccurrence has a 1:1 relationship with ExceptionAppointment

I know I can eager load the ExecptionOccurrence using

`context.Appointments.Include(a => a.ExceptionOcurrences).ToList();`

but how do I change the expression to include the ExceptionAppointment as well?

Cheers
Abs

Comment: Have you tried `context.Appointments.Include(a => a.ExceptionOcurrences.ExceptionAppointment).ToList();`?

Comment: There is no option on the ExceptionOcurrences for an ExceptionAppointment.  Should there be?

Comment: Sorry: `context.Appointments.Include("ExceptionOcurrences.ExceptionAppointment").ToList()`. Does ExceptionOccurence have ExceptionAppointment navigation property?

Comment: Doesnt seem to work :( Yes the ExceptionOccurrence does have an ExceptionAppointment navigation property.

Comment: @LukLed: BTW I am using this approach (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071942/ef-4-3-code-first-custom-icollection-fails-to-catch-new-items).  Maybe at the point of the InsertItem (for the ExceptionOccurrence) the ExceptionAppointment hasnt been loaded?

Comment: What error does it throw (the second solution, with include as string)?

Comment: @LukLed: **My mistake**.  You are correct :)  BTW, can your Include statement be expressed in a lambda?

Comment: Maybe `context.Appointments.Include(a => a.ExceptionOcurrences.Select(eo => eo.ExceptionAppointment)).ToList();`? I don't have access to EF 4 now unfortunately.

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks for taking the time to look into this (much appreciated)

Answer (score 2):

So the answer was (for people who don't read comments):

Without Lambda:

```
context.Appointments.Include("ExceptionOcurrences.ExceptionAppointment").ToList‌​()
```

With Lambda:

```
context.Appointments.Include(a => a.ExceptionOcurrences.Select(eo => eo.ExceptionAppointment)).ToList();
```